How to use joins in hook_views_query_alter()?
I am working on an application that is running on Drupal 10.3.6
I wanted to add role based access to the content visible on Content view (/admin/content).
I have to use a JOIN on 2 tables but the functions like addJoin(), join(), leftJoin(), innerJoin() can't be used because I get this error
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql::join() 
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql::innerJoin() 
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql::leftJoin() 
Error: Call to undefined method Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql::addJoin() 
This is one of the code snippets that I had tried
$query->innerJoin('node__field_itbs', 'field_itbs', 'node_field_data.nid = field_itbs.entity_id');

$query->condition('field_itbs.field_itbs_target_id', $business_line_term_ids, 'IN');

There has been little to no help from GPT & online forums because many of these functions got deprecated in previous version updates.
I have tried using all the available join functions addJoin, join, innerJoin, leftJoin.
None of these work.
I tried creating another logic but for that even the condition() function is an undefined method.
Other approached involved me using addWhere() function but even that doesn't work.

Check the official documentation for the SQL class or the hook
